# Intent does not work from within onClickListener?

Tags: android, buttonclick

In the code i am writing i placed an intent to open a new activity inside an onclicklistener but it is not working. Other code in the listener works, also if i place the same intent outside the listener in an "alternate location" it works. So i am not sure what the problem is here. i would really appreciate any help , thanks.

This is the code used in the tab activity that contains the button for which the Listener is written.

```
public class RemaindersPage extends Activity
{
    com.commsware.pgtracker.RemainderControl rc1;
    int count;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp1,lp2;
    Button btn1,btn2,btn3;
    LinearLayout ll1,ll2;
    Intent i;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.remainders);
        //<Alternate Location> : Intent works if placed here

        TabHost th=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        th.setup();

        TabHost.TabSpec spec=th.newTabSpec("tag1");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        spec.setIndicator("REMAINDERS");
        th.addTab(spec);

        spec=th.newTabSpec("tag2");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        spec.setIndicator("AUTO REMAINDERS");
        th.addTab(spec);

        spec=th.newTabSpec("tag3");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        spec.setIndicator("USER REMAINDERS");
        th.addTab(spec);

        //adding remainder control
        int ht=LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        int wt=LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
        lp1=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(wt,ht);
        ll2=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.tab1_ll);

        //Adding Listeners for the buttons in each tab
        //Tab1
        btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.tab1_add1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                btn1.setText("");
                i=new Intent(RemaindersPage.this,weekly.class);
                startActivity(i);
                //AddRemainder();
            }
        });

        //Tab2
        btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.tab2_add2);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                btn2.setText("");
                //AddRemainder();
            }
        });

        //Tab3
        btn3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.tab3_add3);
        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                btn3.setText("");
                //AddRemainder();
            }
        });


    }

    //draw a new reminder_control instance
    private void AddRemainder()
    {
        rc1=new com.commsware.pgtracker.RemainderControl(RemaindersPage.this);
        rc1.setId(1000+count);
        ll2.addView(rc1,lp1); 
        rc1.SetText("MESSAGE "+Integer.toString(count),0);
        count++;
    }

    //query for all rows in the table and obtain a cursor
    /*private void fillData()
    {
        cursor=dbHelper.fetchAllReminders();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() 
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (dbHelper != null) 
        {
            dbHelper.close();
        }
    }*/
}
```

Comment: Hint: instead of `that`, use `RemaindersPage.this`.

Comment: Have u declared the class in manifest?(weekly.class)

Comment: 'that' was a mistake i have changed the code.

Comment: @Raghu Also the same intent when placed in the location below setContentView() works fine and the new activity opens automatically.

Comment: You are saying this is a `TabAcitivity` but you have used `Activity`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try like this

```
  button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(),
                NextActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
         finish();


    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Change: `i=new Intent(that,weekly.class);`

To: `i=new Intent(RemaindersPage.this, weekly.class);`

and try again

Comment: I did that now , still no difference, also the setText statement works so it seems to enter the Listener but the intent does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the listener the context get lost... You have to retrieve it using v.getContext

Answer (score 0):

What is "that" here??.Use RemaindersPage.this in place of "that". You will get success.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the error is actually in the xml.
The button for which the listener was written was never visible on the screen.
Once i fixed that it was ok.
Totally my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are using `this` as a first parameter of `Intent()` constructor. But since you are in the scope of `OnClickListener()` you will not have the access of `this`. So basically you need to get the context of the current activity. This can be done by calling `getContext()` on the view (the parameter of `onClickListener()`.

```
    `v.getContext()`
```